# Entity Inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, entity

I have 2 Class A and B:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;
    private a1;
}


@Entity
public class B extends A {
    private b1;
}
```

I want to have a C Entity Class which has all A and B attributes (a1, b1 and C's attribute c1).

```
@Entity
public class C extends B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private c1;
```

}

1- When I use Inheritance Strategy InheritanceType.JOINED, it would not copy attributes of A and B into C, in result, Tables A,B and C  will be joind in query time!

2- If I use Inheritance Strategy InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS , it copies attributes of A and B into C, but when I want to query B, it will use UNION with C! 
also it does not permit AUTO ID gerenartion strategy ( Error: Cannot use identity column key generation with  ). Also sequence strategy
 affects performance and concurrency.

How can I have a C Entity Class which has all A and B attributes (a1, b1 and C's attribute c1), without problems mentioned above?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to have a C Entity Class which has all A and B attributes (a1, b1 and C's attribute c1),  without problems mentioned above!

Comment: if you actually have a question (with a ? after it) then EDIT your Post to include the question. Dont use comments!

Comment: if C extends B then you cannot REDEFINE the Id in a subclass. This is the case WHATEVER INHERITANCE strategy you use. Any JPA doc would tell you this

Comment: First, A must be annotated with Entity, not MappedSuperclass. Second, id must not be redefined in C. Third, you don't inherit a class because you want to have the same attributes. You do it because there is a *is a* relationship. If a C is not a B, then C shouldn't inherit B, even if it happens to have similar fields. The union between B and C is done because you said JPA that a C is a B. If your conern is performance, then you shouldn't worry about sequence generation (which is absolutely fine), and you'd better use the third and default strategy: single table.

Comment: 1- A is MappedSuperclass , because I have other entities which inherits A's attributes like B!   2- C is a type of B and that is why it has all attributes of B!

Answer (score 0):

You may use for your case:

1. **TABLE_PER_CLASS** Strategy, and when you need to query B, you should use  `select * from B b where TYPE(b) IN (B)`, in this case JPA musn't use union with C.
2. **SINGLE_TABLE** Strategy, in this case you should define “discriminator column”, for example `mytype`, that has value 'B' or 'C', and you can use query `select * from B where mytype = 'B'` or `select * from C where mytype = 'C'`. Minus B and C be in one table, and B has field `c1` that was always NULL.